# Making equally long columns without using faux columns

Tags: html, css

I have been learning about HTML and CSS this last week and am trying out various things before getting started with a real project.

I have been messing around a bit and this is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/94ZDm/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/94ZDm/1/embedded/result/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>My Website</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="nav">
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="main1"> 
    <h1 id="top"> Hello World!!! </h1>

        <p> First paragraph </p>

        <h2> Things I Must Do Today</h2>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="http://google.be" target="_blank" id="externallink"> Go to the mall </a> </li>
                <li> Shop </li>
                <li> Get gas</li>
                <li> Drive home </li>
            </ul>

        <p><img src="img/koala.jpeg" alt="a koala sitting in a tree" align="left"/>

            Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!</p>

        <p> Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!</p>

        <p> Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!</p>

        <p> Text a lot of text! Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!
            Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!Text a lot of text!</p>

        <p><a href="#top">Top</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="main2"> 
        <p> extra navigation... </p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    &copy; Copyright Blabla Land 2014
</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>


 * {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background: green;
}

.container {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.main-wrap {
overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}

.main1 {
float: left;
width: 652px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}

.main2 {
float: right;
width: 288px;
min-height: 1000px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
} 

footer {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;

text-align: center;
}

#navi li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin-right: 25px;
}

#navi {
text-align: center;
}

a:link {
color: black; 
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color:black;
}

a:hover {
color: #229944;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
color:red;
}

#externallink {
text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
padding: 10px;
}
```

How do I make my content columns equally long (the right one should be as long as the main one) without using faux columns? Faux columns would prevent me from using the current layout? I also don't want to use a specified height, it has to adapt automatically with the content.

Comment: Too many different question in one post. Please restrict yourself of one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. Edited my post. Cheers!

Comment: I didn't see the edit, so my answer below includes answers to all your 3 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it **using CSS table-cells**.

Modify the CSS as follows:

```css
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 980px; /* Container width + 2 x 10px */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
.main1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 652px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
.main2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 288px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

For `.main-wrap`, apply `display: table`, and then `display: table-cell` to the two
child elements `.main1` and `.main2`.

By default, the two child elements will scale to the larger of the two heights.

To get spacing between `.main1` and `.main2`, apply `border-spacing: 10px 0` to get a 10px horizontal spacing around each cell.  This also affects the overall width of the table so the two cells are slightly narrower than intended.

To fix this, set the `.main-wrap` width to 980px, that is, the width of `.container` plus
twice the cell spacing of 10px.

The result is an overflow condition, which you can hide using `overflow: hidden` on `.container`.

Finally, apply `margin-left: -10px` to adjust the centering of the table.

Optionally, use `margin-bottom: 10px` on `.main-wrap` to open up some white space between the main elements and the footer.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/b8Fy7/

Answer (score 0):

1) To make the columns equally long, change the width of the container to twice the width of each of the columns. Set the width of the second column as the same as the first column. If you want them to set their height automatically, just don't specify it. (

```
#container {
width:1304px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#main2 {
float: right;
width: 652px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #efefef;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

2) Both classes and ids work, but classes are generally preferred for css. In the fiddle below, I've changed it to ids just to make sure that the layout doesn't change.

3) '#navi' refers to the list itself, whereas '#navi li' refers to each of the list items in the list.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/94ZDm/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also change their height dynamically using jQuery, if you want two elements to be always the same height even when you change amount of text inside.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7TjfF/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $hi1 = jQuery('#id1').height();
    $hi2 = jQuery('#id2').height();

    jQuery('#id2').css('min-height', $hi1);
    jQuery('#id1').css('min-height', $hi2);
});
```

And here is how a similiar function works when implemented on a site: http://nidrax.eu/pl/about.php (resize browser window to see it work)

Comment: Looks interesting, thank you Nidrax. I will look into it once I get to javascript. For now I'm staying with something I can also actually understand completely. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way, you can use my plugin: https://github.com/Masquerade-Circus/simpleEqualize.js.

Just add it to your proyect and call it like this.

```
$(".main-wrap").simpleEqualize(true, 'div');
```

If the project is responsive, you can call it like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".main-wrap").simpleEqualize(true, 'div');
});
```

Or with a setInterval like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".main-wrap").simpleEqualize(true, 'div');
},100);
```

Comment: I assume this is javascript or something of the sort? I'm not quite there yet but will give it a try soon when I start learning it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

apply eqh-parent class to parent wrapper and eqh-child to its childs and paste script just before end of body. This code is reusable, and working for chrome, FF, IE 8 & above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Faux Columns</title>
    <style>
    .eqh-parent .eqh-child{
        background: #efefef;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    .eqh-child:last-child{
        border-right: none;
    }
    body{
        padding: 30px 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 align="center">Faux Columns</h3>
        <div class="row eqh-parent">
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Built on the trusted foundation of VMware vCloud- Air. Built.io customers now benefit from Mobile Backend-as-a-Service delivered via a pre-approved IT environment that meets enterprise requirements for compliance, security and SLAs through dedicated Built.io.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    AppGyver enables rapid, multi-platform development with tools for non-technical business users and developers alike. By combining the intuitive nature of AppGyver with the power of Built.io's backend, the two companies have joined forces to enable users to build a robust application with an enterprise backend in minutes.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Xamarin is a major front-end player that lets developers create fully native apps for iOS and Android using C#. When combined with Built.io, developers get a complete, best-of-breed solution that allows them to rapidly build robust mobile and web applications powered by a platform built for enterprise.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <p>
                    Student developers at Berkeley's Center for Entrepreneurship & Technology built complex, feature rich apps on top of Built.io, for the 2015 University Mobile Challenge. These bright, young minds are finding new and exciting ways to innovate on top of Built.io's pre-built features, such as intelligent push notifications, geolocation and real-time updates.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row eqh-parent">
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <p>
                    Built on the trusted foundation of VMware vCloud- Air. Built.io customers now benefit from Mobile Backend-as-a-Service delivered via a pre-approved IT environment that meets enterprise requirements for compliance, security and SLAs through dedicated Built.io.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <p>
                    AppGyver enables rapid, multi-platform development with tools for non-technical business users and developers alike. By combining the intuitive nature of AppGyver with the power of Built.io's backend, the two companies have joined forces to enable users to build a robust application with an enterprise backend in minutes.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <p>
                    Xamarin is a major front-end player that lets developers create fully native apps for iOS and Android using C#. When combined with Built.io, developers get a complete, best-of-breed solution that allows them to rapidly build robust mobile and web applications powered by a platform built for enterprise.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row eqh-parent">
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>
                    Built on the trusted foundation of VMware vCloud- Air. Built.io customers now benefit from Mobile Backend-as-a-Service delivered via a pre-approved IT environment that meets enterprise requirements for compliance, security and SLAs through dedicated Built.io.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>
                    AppGyver enables rapid, multi-platform development with tools for non-technical business users and developers alike. By combining the intuitive nature of AppGyver with the power of Built.io's backend, the two companies have joined forces to enable users to build a robust application with an enterprise backend in minutes.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row eqh-parent">
            <div class="eqh-child col-xs-12">
                <p>
                    Built on the trusted foundation of VMware vCloud- Air. Built.io customers now benefit from Mobile Backend-as-a-Service delivered via a pre-approved IT environment that meets enterprise requirements for compliance, security and SLAs through dedicated Built.io.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function setEqualHeight(){
            if($('.eqh-parent').length){ // check if .eqh-parent is available on document 
                $('.eqh-parent').each(function(){
                    if($(this).children().outerWidth() == $(this).width()){
                        $(this).children('.eqh-child').css('min-height', 0);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).children('.eqh-child').css('min-height', 0);
                        var large = $(this).children('.eqh-child').map(function(){
                            return $(this).height();
                        });
                        $(this).children('.eqh-child').css('min-height', large.sort(function(a, b){return b-a})[0]); // sort array in desc order and pick first element to get heighest element within array.
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            setEqualHeight();
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                setEqualHeight();
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```